# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, testcontainers

I am trying to run my spring boot app junit tests inside docker and then create image of that app. Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:alpine-jre as base

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw -B dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:resolve
COPY src ./src

FROM base as test
CMD ["./mvnw", "test"]

FROM base as build
RUN ./mvnw package

COPY target/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar testapp.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "testapp.jar"]
```

Now in some of my unit test cases I am using testcontainers with maven dependency as:-

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am using test containers to up cassandra and redis container while testing.
But somehow the classes that are using testcontainers are failing with exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:109) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:135) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:177) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:314) ~[testcontainers-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242) ~[junit-jupiter-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229) ~[junit-jupiter-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$1(TestcontainersExtension.java:59) ~[junit-jupiter-1.16.0.jar:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:205) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$closeAllStoredCloseableValues$1(ExtensionValuesStore.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.closeAllStoredCloseableValues(ExtensionValuesStore.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.AbstractExtensionContext.close(AbstractExtensionContext.java:74) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.JupiterEngineExecutionContext.close(JupiterEngineExecutionContext.java:53) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.cleanUp(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:222) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.cleanUp(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:57) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$cleanUp$9(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.cleanUp(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:87) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
```

Although everything works perfectly fine when I don't run it inside docker but on my local.

Comment: Since your test is "testcontainer based", and you do the test inside a docker image, you should need: docker-in-docker ("dind", at least for the tests)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding this question because of the irritating behaviour of "Will not retry", there is a simple workaround.

Testcontainers caches the failure to find a Docker environment, and if you are using gradle or another build tool which keeps long-running daemons around, this cached failure will stick around basically forever.

Running `gradle --stop` (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon) will stop any long-running gradle daemons and will effectively clear the cached failure. You may be using a gradle wrapper, in which case you're looking for `./gradlew --stop`.

You can also use `gradle --status` to view running daemons.

Other build tools like `Takari` or `mvnd` (Maven Daemon) will have their own ways of stopping the long-running daemons. For `mvnd`, the command is `mvnd --stop`.

#### References and other reading:

- The original PR where this behaviour was introduced: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/456
- Some discussion about this issue on Github: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/6441

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't add your user to the *docker* group, try:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out, log in again. Check the user has the appropriate groups and launch your app again.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact same problem.

Restart your computer, make sure that docker had finished starting up, rerun the test.

If you want to check that docker is properly running you can try starting up a postgres db in docker with:

```
docker run --name postgres-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

---